# Start AspNetCore Razor App with Razor Errors

Tags: visual-studio, razor

I had a major update on a frontend library, which basically broke all my razor pages.
I would now like to start my razor app in debug with razor runtime compilation and fix each Page one by one, so that I can actually see what happens there.

Unfortunately Visual Stupido won't let me run the app, as long as there are errors on my Razor pages...
Any ideas how to fix that?